# How to view the response return from a parse.com in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse sdk for my application. While i'm fetching details from my parse database using ParseQuery, how i may see the response return from the parse.com? Or in which format the response would be generally?

Answer (score 0):

Parse is going to get [shutdown](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2016/01/28/facebook-to-shut-down-parse-its-platform-for-mobile-developers/?_r=0) soon.
It will be good choice to [migrate your Parse Android App to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **objectId**, you can retrieve the whole **ParseObject** using a **ParseQuery**:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

To get the values out of the ParseObject, there’s a **getX** method for each data type

You can get more information from [this](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/)